# isolate controller to only controller specific scopes

Tags: angularjs

So I have a directive and inside the directive view (html) I put a controller however its affecting the rest of the viewModel (vm). What's the best way to isolate a controller to only control specific viewModel?

That's the structure of the view model and directive, I thought ng-controller="ctrl as vm" would only find vm within the class of "controller" but instead its finding every vm on the page.

Directive:

```
var directive = {

        templateUrl: '/Content/app/core/scaffolding/views/popup.html',
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
          console.log('something')
        }

    };
```

view:

```
<div class="directive">
   <div class="moreVm">
    <a href="" ng-click="vm.goSomewhere" ng-class="{true: 'red'}[vm.someClass]"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="controller" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
      <a href="" ng-click="vm.click()"></a>
      <button ng-click="vm.find()"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried making "ctrl as jvm" but still the same haha, its just a guess.

```
<div class="controller" ng-controller="ctrl as jvm">
      <a href="" ng-click="jvm.click()"></a>
      <button ng-click="jvm.find()"></button>
  </div>
```

Comment: How are you using directive atttribute? Normally attribute directive is used as <input directive />. Can't understand your  usage of "<div class="directive">"

Comment: Yes that's how I'm using it <div directive> i used <div class="directive"> as a sample.

Comment: You problem is not entirely clear. How are you using directive and controller within a directive scope, or the other way? Is it directive controller, or a an external controller? what functionality you want to achieve? Then it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var directive = {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: true,
        bindToController: {},
        controller: "ctrl as vm",
        templateUrl: "/Content/app/core/scaffolding/views/popup.html"
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with an example using directives which may be of some help - [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SoxC3ApsrUdcEVI5gYrJ?p=preview)

As you can see clicking the button in **directive2** does not set the value of `$scope.aValue` in **directive1**.

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', [])

    .directive("directive1", function accountDir() {
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            templateUrl: "directive1.html",
            scope: {},
            controller: function ($scope) {
              $scope.$watch("aValue", function(newValue) {
                console.log(newValue);
              })
            }
        };
    }
    )

    .directive("directive2", function accountDir() {
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            templateUrl: "directive2.html",
            scope: {},
            controller: function ($scope) {
              $scope.setAValue = function () {
                $scope.aValue = 42;
                console.log($scope.aValue);
              }
            }
        };
    }
    );
```

Markup

```
  <body>
    <directive1></directive1>
  </body>
```

directive1.html

```
<directive2></directive2>
```

directive2.html

```
Directive2
<br>
<button ng-click="setAValue()">Set a value</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I not guess wrong,you want do that when ctrl as different names, the directive console.log different value? or in vm but the value within directive is different with out of the directive?

if you want first ,you just make two controller and then set different value;

```
controller('ctrl1',function(){ this.name});
controller('ctrl2',function(){ this.name});
```

else want two

```
directive('myDir',function(){ return {restrict:'AE',scope:{},controller:function(){this.name='haha'}}})
```

and now the value is isolate with outer